# Uninstall pip inside a virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

My pip package is broken inside a virtual environment. I tried to uninstall pip using pip uninstall pip. But it listed all my pip packages which are under the python folder whose path is set in the environment variables. So how do I uninstall pip package specific to a virtualenv? I am using Windows Machine.

Comment: Did you try `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`?

Comment: @OferSadan does it reinstall pip inside the virtual environment?. My path environment variable points to a different python location. So Does it work for this virtual environment?

Comment: I think it is better to remove the virtual environment directory and create a new one.

Comment: to uninstall `pip uninstall pip` will work. It will uninstall pip package
to reinstall download get-pip.py an install it using `python get-pip.py`